# Xcode: How to change text colour of one table view cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uidatepicker

I have a table view showing a date set via a date picker. I want to compare the date picker date to the current date and if date picker is older than the current date i want the date to show in orange. The code i currently have works but it changes the colour in ever cell not just the one that is older. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *Storeddate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Datepicker"];
    NSComparisonResult result;

    result = [today compare:Storeddate];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *Data = [ArrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Data valueForKey:@"dataattribute"]]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Data valueForKey:@"date"]]];

    if (result == NSOrderedDescending) {

        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    else{
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You should do the comparison between `today` and `[Data valueForKey:@"date"]` if you want it to be cell-specific :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `result` is comparing the same two dates every time. You are getting the two values like this:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *Storeddate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Datepicker"];
```

Both of those are constant values (unless you change the `Datepicker` object at some point inbetween loading each cell).

I'm assuming you want to compare the `[Data valueForKey:@"date"]` to `today` instead.